# Why is my footer not aligned at center on pages without a sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, footer

My footer isn't aligned at the center on pages without a sidebar. On pages with a sidebar, the alignment is perfectly fine. Why is this happening? Can anyone help please?

Here's a link to the site I'm working on: http://www.thesuperwomanlifestyle.com/

The home page has no sidebar so the footer isn't aligned at the center. If you check other pages that have a sidebar, the alignment is alright.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code errors, like the missing closing `</p>` and `</div>` tags. Those errors will throw the footer out of alignment. See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   thesuperwomanlifestyle.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.thesuperwomanlifestyle.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Find the source in index.php and footer.php, but that depends on your theme. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.

And fix the BOM file type of your header.php and index.php files, as per the warning in the validation report. Change them to unicode no BOM.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code by using view source page for both home page and inner pages. I found that in home page the  is inside  and in inner pages the  is outside .

So check your PHP template file for inner pages and close the div of "insidewrap" after footer's div.

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons, in your footer you have diferent code in the diferent sections, and there are a image than not loads. Due to you use IDs for the DIVs, should be a good solution make the DIVs floating in the CSS code.

```
<div id='footer_left'>
<img src='http://www.christiflynn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Take-the-Lead3.jpg' />
</div>

<div id='footer_optin'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www1.moon-ray.com/v2.4/include/formEditor/genbootstrap.php?method=iframe&uid=p2c9303f30&version=1"></script>
</div>



#footer_left, footer_optin {
    float:left;
    width: 10em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need to create another `footer-page.php` template. Then, rearrange another footer. Call the footer template by using `get_footer('page');`

Of course, when creating this, you will need to create a new template for footer so you can move it to the left.

If it's possible, we'd like to see your code for footer and the page code, please, so we can solve the problem.